# ngx-print not printing scrollable view

Tags: angular

I haev a query regarding ngx-print package. I tried to google it but found no luck. I have an angular 8 application with angular material framework. I am trying to print a scrollable list in a dialog but the print preview is only showing records which are in the current dialog view and not all records i.e if I have 20 records in the list and only 10 are in the current view, print preview is showing only 10 records which would be printed. My code is on the lines of

```
<div id="print-section">
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
     <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.surname}}, {{element.firstName}} </td>
     </ng-container>
     ---
     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
     <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
   </table>
</div>
<button type="submit"
        printSectionId="print-section"
        ngxPrint> 
    Print 
</button>
```

All this code is a popup dialog. Has anyone else faced same issue? I couldn't find any reference on google and this looks like a very standard requirement in any application. Please point me right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was not with the ngx-print. Adding

```css
@media print {
  #print-section {
    overflow-y: visible !important;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

solved the problem i.e. overriding the scroll behaviour for printing.